# Installing opevcv 3.3.0 on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, .so

I followed this guide https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/ to install opencv on my raspberry pi 3. I am at the step where it asks me to look in my /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages directory to confirm a cv2.so file is present. When I check this directory, however, the directory does not exist. I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong in my install. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo find / -type d -name site-packages 2> /dev/null` to see where it is hiding.

Comment: Should I run the command in the virtual enviorment

Comment: You can run it anywhere.

Comment: I got this /usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Comment: So your `cv2.so` file is in the last of those three places. You should be able to carry on now you know where it is.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help any more. I don't install OpenCV the way that article advocates.

Comment: Do you know of a good up to date website I can follow to reinstall opencv on a blank version of raspbian.